# Regex to clean file with tons of lines

Tags: java, regex, excel, maven

I'm looking for a way to clean a files that contains tons of lines like this :

[image]

What I need to do is to clean all the INFO stuff and only have the dependencies names without all characters behind.

Comment: If you do it line by line : - (.*)

Comment: [Don't post text as image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1393766)

Comment: And how to delete everything that is before the - (.*) ?

Comment: No need to delete. Text after `- ` will be placed in group (indexed as 1 in this case - order is based on `(` order in your regex). So simply use content of that group 1.

Comment: perfect :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Hint: sometimes regexes are nice to write down; but keep in mind that when dealing with a known fixed structure ... a few calls to indexOf() and direct sub-stringing might be the better answer to process "tons" of input.

Comment: *"without all characters behind"* What characters behind? There are no characters *behind* the dependency name, e.g. `junit:junit:jar:4.11:test` is a dependency name and there's no text after that in the line. Show us an example of what you want the result to be. And please replace that picture with text. It's easy enough to copy/paste it in.

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern dependencyRegex = Pattern.compile(" (.+?):(.+?):(.+?):(.+?)$");
```

This would give you the following:

- RegEx-Group 1: artifact group
- RegEx-Group 2: artifact name
- RegEx-Group 3: artifact version
- RegEx-Group 4: artifact scope

Explanation:

- The dependency is described by anything behind the last space character (until the end of the line).
- The four properties are separated by a colon `:`